# Give every new object a new attribute value (participants and start numbers)

Tags: java, object, attributes, addition

My program is a sports competition with event, participant, team, result and program classes. I found a problem during the final testing regarding participants and their start number attribute.

The participant is given a start number when added. The first gets 100, the next 101, 102 and so on. If participant 102 is removed and a new participant is added, the new one also gets number 102, which appears to be my problem. Apparently these start numbers aren't supposed to be reused. Is there a way to give new participants new start numbers that hasn't been given before?

From the Participant class:

```
private int startNumber;

public int getStartNumber() {
        return startNumber;
    }

    public void setStartNumber(int startNumber) {
        this.startNumber = startNumber;
    } 
+ other attributes and methods
```

From the program class:

```
private void addStartNumber(Participant p) {
        if(allParticipants == null || allParticipants.isEmpty()){
            p.setStartNumber(100);      
        }else{
            p.setStartNumber(findLastStartNumber()+1);
        }

    }

    private int findLastStartNumber(){
        int lastNumber = 0;

        for(int i = 0 ; i < allParticipants.size() ; i++){
            lastNumber = allParticipants.get(allParticipants.size()-1).getStartNumber();
        }
        return lastNumber;
    }
```

Comment: Keep an array of deleted numbers and choose the first value of that (if it exists) before incrementing

Comment: Is whoever gave you this assignment okay with you asking for help on the internet? Also, please read about [ask] questions here. Your deadline is *your* deadline, not ours, so talking about it in the question just clutters up the question.

Comment: Any mention of deadline will usually have the exact opposite effect that you're desiring. Just FYI.

Comment: Overt, I guess the user wants the opposite of what u are saying :-)

Comment: You're right Shrikant. My bad. In that case, do exactly what I said _but in reverse_

Comment: @EdCottrell  Thank you for your comment. I wouIdn't ask if I didn't know it was allowed. And I apologize for formulating my question like I did, I'm new to stack overflow. But thank you for the information.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thanks for the information

Comment: @ShrikantHavale thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I understood the problem right then you can hold the last start number in a local variable:

```
private int lastStartNumber = 0;

private int getNextStartNumber(){
    lastStartNumber = lastStartNumber + 1;
    return lastStartNumber;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let the constructor of each participant manage the start numbers.

This is the only code you need for assigning start numbers:

```
class Participant {
    static int nextStartNumber = 100;
    private int startNumber;

    public Participant() {
        this.startNumber = nextStartNumber++;
    }
}
```